# How to use 2 view boxes to create custom control to draw lines?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, viewbox

I know that We can use a view box to simulate a line in xaml

```
<BoxView  
    VerticalOptions="Fill"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    WidthRequest="1"
    Color="Black"/>
```

That would create a vertical line, however I want to create something like:
[image]

I wonder if a grid would be enough to create something like that

How to use a viewbox to draw the vertical line from bottom to top until middle, and then use other view box to middle to right

I was thinking on using a stacklayout instead of a grid and then use 
StackOrientation.Vertical and LayoutOptions.Center but I don´t know exactly how to proceed.

What would be the best or easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have created something similar that you are looking for:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4">

    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4">

    </Border>
</Grid>
```

PS: Just make sure that the controls inside the first border do not cross the first column of the second row inside the grid as the second border is overlapping the first one.

Comment: This is good solution, however Iam not able to use Border in xamarin, what would be the way using Boxview?

Comment: You can use the Frame control in xamarin instead of Border, you might have to play with some of the properties to suit your need but should do your job.